# Send user data to Google Analytics after pageview

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have script that loads data about user that i want to send to Analytics, which loads after GA script and pageview. 
Hi, I want to be able to send data about visit (userId and few dimensions) to analytics after my custom script (which is loaded asynchronously) obtains data about this visit.

How do I send data to Google Analytics, after i set values (eg. ga('set', 'dimension1', 'abc');) if i dont want to use ga('send', 'pageview'); to avoid counting this pageview twice?

I tried to send event, but when i looked at collect script those data was not sent with it.

EDIT: Script looks like this:

```
if(window['ga']) {
    if(utd.UID&&utd.P){
        ga('set','userId',utd.UID);
        ga('set','dimension1',utd.UID);
        ga('set','dimension2',utd.P);
    }
    ga('set','dimension3',utd.DID);
    ga('send','event','uts','accepted',null,null,{nonInteraction:true});
}

if(window['ga']){
    ga('create','UA-XXX-Z','auto','globalTracker');
    if(utd.UID&&utd.P) {
        ga('globalTracker.set','userId',utd.UID);
        ga('globalTracker.set','dimension1',utd.UID);
        ga('globalTracker.set','dimension2',utd.P);
    }
    ga('globalTracker.set','dimension3',utd.DID);
    ga('globalTracker.send','pageview');
}
```

First part doesnt work, but the second one, which sends data to another tracker does.

Comment: You use an event. If it didn't work when you tried you probably made a mistake. Would be helpful if you could include a sample script of what you tried (maybe the event was sent before your async script finished loading or something).

Comment: thanks, i added script code to Question

Comment: I'm assuming you have utd.DID defined already? Running the code in the console complains it's not defined.